# Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to auto populate the google with the help of some data from google sheet.
When i run the autoEntry function which is supposed to submit the response i get a truncated server error. Any help?
error :Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: <meta name="viewport" c... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
at autoEntry(Code:43:26)

```
function autoEntry() {
 
  var ids = run();
  var workBook = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var workSheet= workBook.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var formUrl = ""
  var formData = ""
  var acknowlegdement= "";
  var covid_contact= "";
  var travel = "";
  var work_office_client = "";
  var Line_of_service = "";
  var grade = "";
  var date_visit= "";
  var time_est_arrival= "";
  var time_est_departure= "";
  var noOfRows = workSheet.getRange("J1").getDisplayValue();
  for (i = 2; i <=noOfRows;i++){
    acknowlegdement=workSheet.getRange("A" + i).getDisplayValue();
    covid_contact = workSheet.getRange("B" + i).getDisplayValue();
    travel = workSheet.getRange("C" + i).getDisplayValue();
    work_office_client = workSheet.getRange("D" + i).getDisplayValue();
    Line_of_service = workSheet.getRange("E" + i).getDisplayValue();
    grade = workSheet.getRange("F" + i).getDisplayValue();
    date_visit = workSheet.getRange("G" + i).getDisplayValue();
    time_est_arrival = workSheet.getRange("H" + i).getDisplayValue();
    time_est_departure = workSheet.getRange("I" + i).getDisplayValue();
   
   
    
   
    formUrl = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1ZBx7lxqwE2LDmPYL93U5cnRb_wBMjEz1J9he2JDUiQY/formResponse?&pageHistory=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
    formData ="&entry." + ids[0]+ "=" + acknowlegdement +"&entry." + ids[1]+ "=" + covid_contact + "&entry." + ids[2]+ "=" + travel + "&entry." + ids[3]+ "=" + work_office_client + "&entry." + ids[4]+ "=" + Line_of_service + "&entry." + ids[5]+ "=" + grade +"&entry." + ids[6]+ "=" + date_visit+"&entry." + ids[7]+ "=" + time_est_arrival +"&entry." + ids[8]+ "=" + time_est_departure
   
    var finalUrl = formUrl + formData
   
    var options = {
     "method" : "post"
     
   
   
    };
    var res =UrlFetchApp.fetch(finalUrl,options);
    
 
  }
}

function getPreFillEntriesMap_(id){
  var form = FormApp.openById(id);
  var items = form.getItems();
  var newFormResponse = form.createResponse();
  var itms = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    var response = getDefaultItemResponse_(items[i]);
    if(response){
      newFormResponse.withItemResponse(response);
      itms.push({
        id: items[i].getId(),
        entry: null,
        titile: items[i].getTitle(),
        type: "" + items[i].getType()
      });
    }
  }

  var ens = newFormResponse.toPrefilledUrl().split("&entry.").map(function(s){
    return s.split("=")[0];
  });
  ens.shift();

  return itms.map(function(r, i){
    r.entry = this[i];
    return r;
  }, ens);
}

function getDefaultItemResponse_(item){
  switch(item.getType()){
    case FormApp.ItemType.TEXT:
      return item.asTextItem().createResponse("1");
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
      return item.asMultipleChoiceItem()
        .createResponse(item.asMultipleChoiceItem().getChoices()[0].getValue());
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
      return item.asCheckboxItem()
         .createResponse([item.asCheckboxItem().getChoices()[0].getValue()]);
     case FormApp.ItemType.DATETIME:
      return item.asDateTimeItem()
        .createResponse(new Date());
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.DATE:
      return item.asDateItem()
        .createResponse(new Date());
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
      return item.asListItem()
        .createResponse(item.asListItem().getChoices()[0].getValue());
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.PARAGRAPH_TEXT:
      return item.asParagraphTextItem().createResponse("some paragraph");
        
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX_GRID:
      return item.asCheckboxGridItem().createResponse([item.asGridItem().getColumns[0], item.asGridItem().getRows[0]]);
     
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.DURATION:
      return item.asDurationItem().createResponse(2, 20, 20);
     
      break;
    case FormApp.ItemType.GRID:
      return item.asGridItem().createResponse([item.asGridItem().getColumns[0], item.asGridItem().getRows[0]]);
       
      break;
   case FormApp.ItemType.SCALE:
      return item.asScaleItem().asScaleItem().createResponse(1);
       
      break;
   case FormApp.ItemType.TIME:
      Logger.log(item.asTimeItem())
     return item.asTimeItem().createResponse(1,1);
       
      break;
    default:
      return undefined;
  }
}
function run(){
 var obj= JSON.stringify(getPreFillEntriesMap_("1ZBx7lxqwE2LDmPYL93U5cnRb_wBMjEz1J9he2JDUiQY"),null,"  ");
  Logger.log(obj)
  var entries_id= [];
  var stringify = JSON.parse(obj);
  for (var i = 0; i < stringify.length; i++) {
   // Logger.log(stringify[i]['entry'])
    entries_id.push(stringify[i]['entry'])
   
 
}
  return entries_id;
 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to use the HTML frontend to send a response, use the Apps Script service. To do so it works like this:

1. Create a new response with `from.createResponse()`
2. For each item get the actual type (with the `asXXX` methods) and then create an item response with `createResponse(value)`
3. Add each item response, add it to the response with `response.withItemResponse(itemResponse)`
4. Submit the response with `response.submit()`

### References

- [Form.createResponse() (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#createresponse)
- [FormResponse.withItemResponse(response) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#withitemresponseresponse)
- [TextItem.createResponse(response) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/text-item#createresponseresponse)
- [FormResponse.submit() (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#submit)

Comment: @GeorgeArthur What do you mean by pass the URL?

Comment: var res =UrlFetchApp.fetch(finalUrl,options);

Comment: can you write out how i should use it

Comment: I don't understand why you need to fetch. `submit` already submits the responses. What am I missing?

Comment: @GeorgeArthur You are using the fetch to submit the response. `response.submit()` already does that without need of using fetch.

Comment: @GeorgeArthur How did it fail?

Comment: there was no response

Comment: Try submitting an answer to a simpler form: create a new form with only a single text question. Create a new Apps Script standalone project. Open the form with `FormApp.openById(<id>)`, and try submitting a response.

Comment: did that still no response , can you take a look at the code.

Comment: I don't have the code you made. What did you do?

Comment: can you  edit it with the code i pasted  earlier ?